# ip addr does not chage

Tags: networking, wireless, router, ip-address

I am trying to change my wifi router.
The old one (zz-home-tm) uses subnet 192.168.12.*, the new one (zz-home) - 192.168.0.*.
At the moment both routers are running.
Even if I switch to zz-home, the computer shows 192.168.12.201 ip address and 192.168.0.1 does not ping (192.168.12.1 ping works).   Tried to set up ip addr manually - same thing.
The new router has 2 hotspots with the same ip range, 5Gz and 2.4Gz. Both show the same results.
If I connect via ethernet, ip addr is correct.
I see this issue on two laptops, one Ubuntu, the other Mac. My 3rd machine, also Ubuntu laptop works as expected. Very weird.
Can anyone help?

Comment: sounds like you didn't actually connect to the new router then (or at the very least, you didn't disconnect from the old one), if you're still able to ping the 192.168.12.* addresses. How are these two routers set up/connected, if at all?

Comment: Try removing the connection profile for the old WiFi router. Also verify using another device that the IP subnet of the new router was actually set up like you say

Answer (score 0):

Tried many things until blue in the face, nothing worked while the old router was on.
Seems like interference issue.
It's ok now.
Thank you anyway.